# Why is my Embedded Javascript (EJS) not displaying my error.status value?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using ejs, node.js & express among other packages

Why are the error.status and error.stack values not being displayed when the page renders? I'm sure it has to do with the error variable being undefined or not accessible inside of the ejs file but i'm not sure how to declare it or import it to be accessible.
[Rendered 404 page with no error.status or error.stack displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYkLz.png)

This is my error.ejs file

```
<%- include partials/header.ejs %>

<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>

<h2><%= error.status %></h2>
<pre><%= error.stack %></pre>

<%- include partials/footer.ejs %>
```

This is my header.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Quartile </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/66fd6114b0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you pass the error from render? Something along the line of

```
res.render("error", { title: "Error", error: error.array() })
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out before I saw your response but I am still a little confused about how the errors are generated in the first place? I have a response to this below that describes it a bit more, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to pass through a value that I defined as a placeholder, the variable needs to be passed through in the app.js file when you res.render the error file.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  err.status = 404;
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error',{errorStatus: err.status}); // 
});
```

I still don't quite understand how the err.status value is determined or populated if i don't hard code it, if it is actually created when a real error occurs somewhere else, does it have no value at the moment because I have no actual errors? Or am I always going to have to define it myself? It seems like there must be a way for and error value you to be automatically generated and I can just have it display a changing variable but I don't understand how to go about doing this.